# Data updates in a running journey and displaying most updated data on an email

Tags: journeybuilder

I have an installation journey that helps clients engaged as they wait for their installation date.

We send them a series of 6 emails with next steps through the journey and remind them of their installation date. I have a data extension that's updated by an Automation as once the customer enters the journey their installation date could change. .  I also use decision splits to see if certain fields have a certain status.

My question is:
Once a contact has entered a journey, are the fields within a data extension static? Or will those fields be updated as I have an automation that runs  to update those fields when action is taken.

My problem is when I have updated and changed a customers installation date the new installation date is not being properly displayed on the next email templates the original installation is, even though the installation date is updated on the data extension.
I am using an Entry Source of a Data Extension and I am using contact data in my decision  splits and my data extension is connected to the Data Design.

Example I send templates 1-2 with an Installation Date of August 1st. The customer makes a change and the installation date is now August 14th  emails 3, 4 ,5 , 6 are still showing the original date of August 1st.

Answer (score 0):

Please see this article as it talks about journey data.
[Dynamic content when email is used in a Journey](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/250064/dynamic-content-when-email-is-used-in-a-journey)

Once a journey is activated all of its content, settings, etc. are set in stone.

This also includes the data in the de at the time of entry. Nothing can edit it. what you can do however is do a lookup.